# ERROR: cannot execute nextval() in a read-only transaction - PostgreSQL

Tags: spring, postgresql

I can see internal server error on my app developed on spring mvc, using wildfly as the webserver and database is `PostgreSQL`. What does this exception mean?

```
ERROR: cannot execute nextval() in a read-only transaction
```

It was working all fine before. I tried to look for the solution here on stackoverflow but didn't find anything that could fix this issue.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What's the solution? what does this exception show?

Comment: It says that you cannot use `nextVal()`, which increments a sequence, thus being a WRITE operation, in a read-only transaction. You probably were in a read-write transaction before and your config switched to read-only transactions for reasons we cannot investigate with simply the error message.

Comment: yes, sounds like I am doing something that's related to write operation while the transaction is in read-only mode.

Comment: Now you have to find out how and/or why your DAL created read-only transactions. Maybe you're just connected with a RO user.

Comment: due to large dataset in the table, I got java heap space exception, which might have mixed up the config or the transaction got stuck in some state.

Answer (score 10):

The function [`nextval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) is used to increment a sequence, which modifies the state of the database.

You get that error because you are in a read-only transaction. This can happen because

1. You explicitly started a read-only transaction with `START TRANSACTION READ ONLY` or similar.
2. The configuration parameter `default_transaction_read_only` is set to `on`.
3. You are connected to a streaming replication standby server.

If `default_transaction_read_only`is set to `on`, you can either start a read-write transaction with

```
START TRANSACTION READ WRITE;
```

or change the setting by editing `postgresql.conf` or with the superuser command

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET default_transaction_read_only = off;
```

Comment: I have extended the answer to cover this.

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out `nextval()` actually updates the database to get a new sequence, so can't be used in a transaction that is marked as read only.

As you're using `Spring` I suspect this means that you're using the spring-transaction support.  If you're using annotation based transaction support, then you'd get a read only transaction if you have

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
```

That means that when spring starts the transaction it will put it into read only mode.

Remove the `readOnly=true` bit and a regular writable transaction is created instead.

Spring transaction control at http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Answer (score 0):

I means exactly what it says, here is example:

```
t=# create sequence so49;
CREATE SEQUENCE
t=# begin;
BEGIN
t=# select nextval('so49');
 nextval
---------
       1
(1 row)

t=# set transaction_read_only TO on;
SET
t=# select nextval('so49');
ERROR:  cannot execute nextval() in a read-only transaction
t=# end;
ROLLBACK
```

I presume you connected as so called ro user, which is user with "transaction_read_only" set to true, EG:

```
t=# select rolconfig from pg_roles where rolname ='ro';
         rolconfig
----------------------------
 {transaction_read_only=on}
(1 row)
```

you can switch that off for your user of course, but this is out of scope I believe

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-transaction.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason of this error was because I was conncting to specific node of the cluster instead of main HAR cluster url. At some moment the node switched its status and this error has been arised. So, check your connection first, if there is a chance that it is a cluster.

Comment: This is exactly the issue I am running into, connecting to standby server. Wonder where to find the HAR cluster url. My url is currently like //node1:port1,node2:port2, node3:port3/. Any clue is appreciated. Thanks